# docker-compose: 2-3 min downtime when I change an image in the azure registry

Tags: azure, docker

I set up the following application:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx: 
    image: myregistry.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  app2:
    image: myregistry.azurecr.io/app2:latest
    container_name: app2
    expose: 
      - 8080
```

nginx.conf:

```
events {
}
http{
server {
listen 80 default_server;
location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    proxy_pass http://app2:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
}
```

And it works well: a reverse proxy asks for username/password before serving the content.

Now, the app2 constantly changes, and I set up a script that uploads a new image to the azure registry.

And here come my pain: each time I upload a new version I keep getting 502 - Gateway error from nginx for about 2-3 mins.

After this time the application is available again. How come? Is there a way to prevent it? Where is the 24/7 promised to me by azure? :(

Comment: What do you mean by "the app2 constantly changes"?

Comment: It's the app I'm working to, so I make deploys frequently. Each deploy repackages a new docker image replacing the previous one. Thanks to azure's "continuous deploy" feature each push to the registry replaces this image in my configuration

Comment: And you're using App Service I guess?

Answer (score 0):

When you update some parts of the container settings, in this case the image the container restarts and it depends on your application on how much it takes for it to be started back. Consider using [rolling updates](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config) with docker swarm for less downtime or optimizing your application.

NGINX also caches DNS queries so it may still point for quite a while to the stopped container until the cache updates. See [this documentation entry](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for more details

Comment: I'll look at it but it is a very simple spring boot application and on my PC it comes up in at most 10 secs, I can understand 30 sec, 1 min but 2-3 mins is really too much

Comment: @Phate depending on the network speed, size of the image and the source of the image (either local docker registry or docker hub) it may take a while to pull it and start it.

Comment: Maybe it's ngnix fault! Updated the thread with my nginx conf, in the mean time I'll search how to disable every cache